# Stanza throws "KeyError: 'feat_dropout'"

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I am using the [CLTK library](http://cltk.org/) to do NLP with ancient Greek. I recently upgraded Python from 3.8.9 to 3.9.9 and since then, whenever I try to do even the simplest things (e.g. [the quickstart code](https://docs.cltk.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)), I get the error `KeyError: 'feat_dropout'`. The stack trace tracks it to `\site-packages\stanza\models\tokenization\trainer.py`, line 98. I've seen [one instance](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/issues/839) of the same error and tried the solution there, but got nowhere. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

CLTK currently (late 2021) requires models and code for Stanza version 1.2.3. There was a change in the Stanza model format whereby certain models from version 1.2.3 are no longer valid in version 1.3. CLTK has not yet updated those models to be compatible with 1.3, so you will need to either downgrade Stanza to 1.2.3 or encourage CLTK to upgrade their models.

For more information, see: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/issues/839 .